# Behavior of jQuery bind() when using namespace

Tags: javascript, events, namespaces

Currently I'm dealing with namespaces in javascript. As a first step I build a test page.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Namespace</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var NSVB = NSVB || {};
NSVB.sub = {
  init: function(){
    alert("NSVB rocks");
    $("#click-test").bind("click",NSVB.sub.clicktest());
  },
  clicktest: function(){
    alert("clicked");
  }
}

NSVB.sub.init = function(){
  alert("NSVB rocks overwirtten");
  $("#click-test").bind("click",NSVB.sub.clicktest());
}

$(document).bind("load", NSVB.sub.init());
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="click-test">click to test</p>
</body>
</html>
```

What I expect my code to do is:

- define the namespace with the function init() and clicktest()
- overwrite the function init()
- handle click event on #click-test when I click it

What my Code does:

- define the namespace with the function init() and clicktest()
- overwrite the function init()
- call clicktest()
- when I click nothing happens!!

I really don't get it! Hope someone could help.

Thanks in advance.

## EDIT

After some testing I've have done the following:

Remove parenthesis

```
$("#click-test").bind("click",NSVB.sub.clicktest);
```

Replace

```
$(document).bind("load", NSVB.sub.init);
```

With (one of them, what you prefer to use)

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",NSVB.sub.init,false);
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
NSVB.sub.init();
});
```

Everything works fine and as expected!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't bind the function but the result of the function, that is nothing.

Change

```
$(document).bind("load", NSVB.sub.init());
```

to

```
$(document).bind("load", NSVB.sub.init);
```

You have the same problem elsewhere (except of course if `NSVB.puzzle.clicktest()` returns a function):

```
    $("#click-test").bind("click",NSVB.puzzle.clicktest());
```

Comment: I've tested your changes, but now nothing happens! In my example the function init() was called as expected, but the function clicktest() was called immediately and not when I click #click-test.

Comment: No, your function init() wasn't called as expected, it was called immediately, before the document loads. What I meant for the #click-test problem is that you must remove the parenthesis : `$("#click-test").bind("click",NSVB.puzzle.clicktest);`. Whether it will work will depend on the content of this function of course.

Comment: Ok, now I'm totally confused!! I've removed the parenthesis as you said! But, init() will not be called on load. But when i do this  `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",NSVB.sub.init,false);` everything is fine!?!?